# PowerShell Invoke-Command to restart local computer

Tags: invoke-command

I'm writing a build script for a series of machines with a PowerShell GUI.
Essentially, an engineer builds a VM, runs the GUI, selects the type of build they want to perform, and then the script:

- joins the device to the domain
- renames it (if applicable)
- Reboots the device
- Installs prerequisite software
- Reboots the device
- Installs the required software
- Reboots the device

When I run the script from the target machine, the device gathers the data, and passes it over to the remote machine. The remote machine executes the script and triggers the target machine to reboot... but then nothing happens. The script execution just terminates (or so it seems).
The script is configured to wait on the remote machine for the target machine to finish restarting... I've used the following command for this:

```
Restart-Computer -ComputerName $device -Credential $credObject -Wait -For WinRM -Force
```

Pretty straight forward.

The command used to kick off the remote script is:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $global:DC1 -Credential $global:credObject -FilePath 'C:\Provisioning\RemoteProvisioning.ps1' -ArgumentList $hashTable -InDisconnectedSession -InformationAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Any ideas why the command would just terminate, and do nothing once the reboot is initiated?